# How to change the track's shape of a material design slider?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, material-design

I cannot find any information on how to change the shape of the track of the material design slider.

I tried setting a `shapeAppearanceOverlay` but it changes nothing, as the track still remains pill-shaped. My goal is to make the track a rectangle with sharp, cut corners.

[image: my code]

Here is LevelMeterChannel, which is just a class I use to convert the regular slider into a vertical slider[image]